# How to change Selected Value attribute/property on runtime?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here is the aspx/page file generated:

[screenshot](http://imgur.com/HB99v)

The controls were created by parsing XML using XSLT. Is it possible to change the selected values by running some lines of code using ASP.NET or just plain ASP, or maybe even javascript being called from code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery (which you should consider because it's awesome) you could do that by doing the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function)({
         $('select[name="sel_Option"]').val('1');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, once you have the reference to the `select` element (either via `getElementById` or by `getElementsByName`) you could use

```
function setSelected(selectBox, valueToSelect){
    selectBox.value = valueToSelect;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/DSqXe/

You could also use the [selectedIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp) property:

```
function setSelected(selectBox, value){
    for(var i = 0; i < selectBox.length; i++){
        if(selectBox.options[i].value === value){
            selectBox.selectedIndex = i;
        }
    }
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/DSqXe/1/